# Unnecessary border display on UILabel only in retina display

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, retina

I have an UILabel and its displays unnecessary borders only in retina display devices. please see the attached image.

any answer will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried in device and got sam UI effect/

Comment: @agent_stack yes I have tried on the actual device. Same result.

Comment: are you used the any UI for background

Comment: Do [Debugging View Hierarchies](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html) and check what is that black line.

Comment: Do you create label programmatically or from interface builder? Or do you modify label? Show your code, if it possible

Comment: I only subclass from the UILabel. please find the debug description below.

<LabelView: 0x7cfeb720; baseClass = UILabel; frame = (5 31.1364; 152.822 25.2533); text = '9526300011110240001'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7cfeb630>>

Comment: @svvoff I create it programmatically

Comment: put the code of creating Lable